# Filter rows by full name

Tags: sql, .net

I have a column with a full name I need to filter like this:

For example, this is my grid:

```
Name        | Phone      
dan liza    | 9758856526
dana Lori   | 8855656264
```

If I type in the filter textbox "Lori dana" I want it to find it.
I can type only "dana" or "Lori" or the full name but "Lori" and then "dana" not in the same order as​ in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Split the filter input into terms (in this case, words) then require that each word is present. Like so:

If you're using Linq with Entity Framework:

```
String textBoxInput = "Lori dana";
String[] terms = textBoxInput.Split( (Char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ); // Splitting on `null` splits on all whitespace.


IQueryable<People> q = yourDbContext.People;
foreach( String term in terms )
{
    q = q.Where( p => p.Name.Contains( term ) );
}
List<People> filteredPeople = await q.ToListAsync();
```

If you're using Dynamic SQL (note this particular approach is not vulnerable to SQL injection):

```
String textBoxInput = "Lori dana";
String[] terms = textBoxInput.Split( (Char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ); 

SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder( @"

SELECT
    *
FROM
    People
WHERE
" );

for( Int32 i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++ ) 
{
    if( i > 0 ) sql.AppendLine( "    AND" );

    cmd.Parameters.Add( "@term" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = '%' + terms[i] + '%';
    sql.AppendLine( "    [Name] LIKE @term" + i );
}

cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();

using( SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) )
{
    // etc
}
```

Comment: hi thx for your answer, no I am using ado.net in this project this is what i have try to do : 
 ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", "CustName", toolStripTextBox2.TextBox.Text);

it's work fine if I type first or the last name separated or I type the full name in the exact order like in the DB but If the order are not the same I get nothing

Comment: @TechMan If you're using ADO.NET then use a `DataView` to wrap your `DataTable`. You can also use a custom filter predicate with `DataGridView`.